# solve equation using fixed point in scilab?

Tags: matlab, scilab, fixed-point-iteration

I have a equation `f(x)=exp(x)+3x^2`, `f(x)=0`, `x=?` then I use `scilab` to solve that equation using fixed point iteration this is my code

```
function fixed_point(fung,x0,err)
x=zeros(100);
ea = 100;
i = 1;
x(i)=x0;
printf(" \t i \t x(i) \t       ea(%%)");
printf("\n\t %d \t %f \t %f", i, x(i), abs(ea));
while (abs(ea) >err) do
    i=i+1;
    z =x(i-1);
    x(i) = evstr(fung)+z;
    ea =100*(x(i)-x(i-1))/x(i);
    printf("\n\t %d \t %f \t %f", i, x(i), abs(ea));
end

printf("\n Akar = %f", x(i));
endfunction
```

then I call it using:

```
fixed_point ('exp(z)-(3 .* z .*z)',0.00000000001,0.5)
```

I got `x(i)=inf` at last, but I think that's not the answer,  can someone explain to me what's wrong with my code?

Comment: I don't understand the method you are trying to implement. Specially here: `x(i) = evstr(fung)+z;` Here you are calculating `f(x(i-1))+x(i-1)`, could you explain this method or link the algorithm?

Comment: There are no real solutions: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=f%28x%29%3Dexp%28x%29%2B3x%5E2

Comment: thanks for your comment, i use fixed point iteration, https://mat.iitm.ac.in/home/sryedida/public_html/caimna/transcendental/iteration%20methods/fixed-point/iteration.html , http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_iteration, function x(i)=evst... means x(i)=f(z)+z or x(i)=f(x(i-1))+x(i-1)  @Daniel

Answer (score 1):

Let's divide the answer to "subproblems":

1. In general: don't use numerical methods if you don't have an idea of solution. As Daniel showed, this equation doesn't have any solution in reals. If you have a reasonable x0, plot its neighborhood first!
2. In general: is your goal solving the equation or implementing that method? Matlab has e.g. `fsolve` function (and you've added matlab tag as well as scilab) or, if you want to design your own function, the [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) works pretty well on these easily differentiable functions (sin, exp, x^n...).
3. In particular: add to your code something that allow you to escape the while loop if the solution doesn't converge. Than your output should be "DOESN'T CONVERGE" which is definitely better than the mysterious `inf` (e.g. break the loop `if i>1e3` or something like that).